# Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, file-upload

I work on shopping site with spring boot and react. When I try to create a new product, I fill some input and images. But on submit I get 400 error code. Error: Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile>` out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1095] (through reference chain: com.shopping_app.model.request.CreateProductRequest["images"])]

- In React

  ```
  upload = () => {

   const formData = new FormData()

   for (const image of this.state.images) {
     formData.append('image', image)
   }

   formData.append('product', {
     categories: this.state.categories,
     brand: this.state.brand,
     colors: this.state.colors,
     sizes: this.state.sizes,
     name: 'product 1',
     price: 100,
     description: 'description',
   })

   Axios.post('http://localhost:7070/test', {
     productRequest: {
       categories: this.state.categories,
       brand: this.state.brand,
       colors: this.state.colors,
       sizes: this.state.sizes,
       name: 'product 2',
       price: 100,
       description: 'description',
     },
     images: formData,
   }).then((res) => console.log(res.data))
  ```

  }
- In Spring Boot

  ```
  @PostMapping(value = "/test")
   public void test(@RequestBody CreateProductRequest createProductRequest)
   {
       productService.createProduct(createProductRequest);
   }


  CrateProductRequest

  public class CreateProductRequest
  {
    private ProductRequest productRequest;

    private List<MultipartFile> images;

    ... constructors, getters and setters
  }
  ```

  Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The spring controller for uploading(POST-ing) multipart file should look like this:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public void test(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
....
....
}
```

If you need Multiple files upload with request body, then

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public void test(@RequestPart("images") MultipartFile[] images, @RequestPart("productRequest") CreateProductRequest productRequest){
....
....
}
```

Please check this [blog](https://medium.com/@pankajsingla_24995/multipart-request-with-request-body-using-spring-boot-and-test-using-postman-6ea46b71b75d#:%7E:text=The%20trick%20here%20is%20to,creates%20a%20multipart%2Fmixed%20request.)

Comment: Yes, I know it, and its work if I just send formData in react. But I want to send an object that contain images and another information about of product

Comment: Ohh in that case, you need the second option. I updated my answer. @sefterm-zade